# Algorithm to find raycast to "special" capsule

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, intersection, raycasting

I have two circles joined together like this:
[image: Capsule with 2 radius]

And I have a point inside the shape, and I would like to cast a ray in a direction from that point onto the shape. In order to retrieve the casted position on the edge of the shape.

[image: Ray inside capsule]

My first thought will be to raycast with the 2 segments joining the 2 circles. And if there is no success hit, I'll raycast with the 2 circles and take the farthest hit position. Is there a better solution? More efficient computation-wise?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: This already seems like a reasonably efficient way to approach it; can you show any code? Do some benchmarks to see if you **really** need to optimize it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I have the pseudo code for now, same thing as above with more details. I am going to implement that, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is suppose that you have direction vector of ray `D=(dx, dy)` and source point is inside of capsule

If you have central axis, use it's direction vector A, otherwise get direction vector S, S of any segment.

At first decide what segment might be intersected: get cross product `A x D` or `S x D`and look at it's sign. Positive sign denotes that you have to check only intersection with the "left" segment, negative one - intersection with the "right" segment.